# Is there any possible way to edit the face points that track from te kinect

Tags: c#, wpf

currently I am doing the project of detecting the face point from the kinect and I need to edit the face point that I identified, and further I need to edit and make a different face, how to do it?

Comment: If you need a different face point *and* face, why even bother detecting it? Set the face point of the face you want - done.

Comment: A different face means the edited face which we have obtained from the kinect. So in order to do this first have to track the face and next have to identify the points and i need a way to change the positions of those two to five points in order to change and get the next face. Hope you understood thanks in advance.